# On Ionic4, how to capitalize the first letter of all the words except prepositions of a string?

Tags: angular, ionic4

I have a name on a list and I'd like to format it correctly, I searched a little and find out [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-capitalize), but I couldn't install it on Ionic 4 and I don't know if it ignores the propositions

I'd like to format it in a simple way like this, what do I have to do?

```
<p class="info">Cliente: {{ pedido.pessoa.data.nome | capitalize }}</p>
```

`JOSE DA SILVA` should be formated to `Jose da Silva`

Comment: I would propose to just construct your own custom pipe.  it is quite straightforward and you can tailor for the exceptions of the propositions if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add text-transform: capitalize to your css class per the Ionic docs

https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities if you have to ignore certain words dynamically that would involve making a custom pipe where you hard code the list of excluded words to be filtered from the start casing.

Comment: Yeah, I know the class, I'm working on the pipe, but it keeps giving me an not found pipe after I creating it

Comment: In that case if you’re using lazy loading create a module for the pipe and import it into the module for the component that uses the pipe.